# How can I connect to a database in Spring using configuration files?

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring, spring-mvc

I tried to connect to a mysql database using Spring MVC but I don't know why the datasource properties are not saved. It gives me some exception like authentification failed but I've saved the connection details in a properties file.

This is the web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:main/java/containers/dao-context.xml
            classpath:main/java/containers/service-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>


    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <resource-ref>
        <description>MySQL Datasource example</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/DataSource</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>

</web-app>
```

This is DAO context for my accounts which includes the datasource bean with the configuration properties:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="username" value="${username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${password}" />
        <property name="url" value="${url}" />
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${driver}" />
    </bean>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:configuration.properties" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="business.users_management" />
    <context:annotation-config />
</beans>
```

this is the configuration file:

```
username = raoul
password = cefere
driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gamedatabase
```

And lastly the AccountsDAO class :

```
@Component("accounts")
public class AccountsDAO implements UsersCRUD {
    private List<Account> accounts;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbc;


    @Autowired
    public void setJdbc(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbc = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAccount(Account account) {
        BeanPropertySqlParameterSource params = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(account);
        return jdbc.update("INSERT into accounts VALUES (:username, :password,, :email, :name)", params) == 1;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Account> getAllAccounts() {
        return jdbc.query("SELECT * FROM accounts", (resultSet, i) -> {
            return createAccount(resultSet);
        });
    }

}
```

These are the errors : It seems like the username and password for connecting to the database are set to default by mysql ...

```
INFO: Loading properties file from class path resource [configuration.properties]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'Gustavo'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:390)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:470)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:480)
    at business.users_management.AccountsDAO.getAllAccounts(AccountsDAO.java:37)
    at business.Main.main(Main.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'Gustavo'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2151)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1902)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1412)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'Gustavo'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:996)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:870)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1659)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1206)
```

Comment: Can you please try with hard coding the values and see if you still get the error?

Comment: Instead of reading from properties file put the actual values

Comment: Now i get this error .... I use mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.38      The server time zone value 'GTB Daylight Time' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.)

Comment: Ok now I think it's able to connect so that the previous error good

Comment: Ok so do you have any idea how to solve these timezone issues ?

Comment: That's what I am searching for. Seeing this error the first time

Comment: jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC try to add this

Comment: It finally works, thank you very much sir !

Comment: Wc will post the answer can you please upvote the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please put the actual values in your config and try jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&use‌​LegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC try to add this